# "Background-size: " is not affecting background image HTML CSS Flask

Tags: html, css, flask

It seems no matter what I set "background-size: " to in my css file, the background image size still stays chopped and too small. I've tried background-size: cover; as well as background-size: 100% 100%;
and either way my background image is relegated to a little strip at the top of the page.

my css

```
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        background: transparent;
    }



h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

body {

  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: verdana;

}


#banner{
  background-image: url(images/home.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

my html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Algernon Industries</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" />


  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="banner">
      <h1>saasdf</h1>


    </div>
    <a href="/art">A R T</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

my python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("homepage.html")

@app.route('/art')
def art():
    return render_template("art.html")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: What if you specify a width and a height in pixels instead of %?

Comment: wow that actually does work though it seems a bit unwieldy to have to set it to exact pixels. better than nothing though, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is:

```
body{
   width: 100%:
}
```

Remember that in the DOM, the html is the root element, and body is the child of html.

Setting the body to 100% width, when there is no width specified in your html selector, makes the width redundant. HTML doesn't automatically occupy 100% of the width and height of the web page.

The proof to this is, if you set a specific width and height in pixels to your image container, it'll resize normally.

If you want this to work, you need your container to occupy a very specific space on the web page.

Usually for banners, they occupy a rather large portion of the page. Usually `height: 40-70vh`

Comment: AH you are correct. I got it working perfectly now. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad it works now. Please mark it as the answer.